# Assumption of equal prior message probabilities in the standard proofs of the converse of Shannon's theorem

Tags: it.information-theory

One of the first steps in the standard proofs for [the (weak) converse of the Shannon's theorem (a.k.a. noisy-channel coding theorem) for the discrete memoryless sources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem#Weak_converse_for_discrete_memoryless_channels) is the assumption that messages are drawn from the uniform distribution.  This assumption is made without justification (e.g. see [the sketch of the proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem#Weak_converse_for_discrete_memoryless_channels) on wikipedia or [the standard text by Cover and Thomas](http://books.google.com/books?id=VWq5GG6ycxMC&lpg=PA1&dq=cover%20and%20thomas%20information%20theory&pg=PT195#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

I am wondering about the concrete mathematical basis for this assumption.  I intuitively understand the reason: regardless of the channel, it's the output of the most efficient source coder (which passes the message to the channel coder), as non-uniformity in the message distribution results in the lower entropy of the source (which would imply the existence of a more efficient source code).  Thus, it seems to me that the source could only gain from uniformity.  However, I am at a loss formulating this mathematically and thus am unsure of my intuition--hence the question to the community.

Comment: For alphabets with $2^{nR}$ codewords and possibly non-uniform messages, the normalized (i.e. $\times \frac{1}{n}$) entropy of your alphabet (say $R_0$) should be less than the channel capacity to achieve a vanishing error rate (The proof follows the same steps as in e.g. the Wikipedia article.). $R_0$ is the "effective rate" you can get out of your source anyway even though the alphabet appears to provide possibly a "much larger rate" $R$ (since it has $2^{nR}$ codewords.). Is this what you are looking for?